# While loop in Julia

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, global-variables, julia

The following code, while admittedly simple, is confusing. Why is the second increment necessary and doesn't the continue statement keep the flow within the first if conditional? At what point is the second if conditional checked?

```
i = 1

while i < 20
  if (i % 2) == 0
    println(i)
    global i += 1
    continue
  end

  global i += 1
  if i >= 10
    break
  end
end
```

I have started teaching myself Julia and the aforementioned syntax looks rather alien.

Thank you.

Comment: the first if condition checks if i is even number and if it is then it prints it and increments it, incrementing will cause i to become odd number so in the next iteratio the first condition will fail, cuasing i to be incremented by 1  and then second condition will be checked.

Comment: the second if will be checked in 1st,3rd,5th, 7th, 9th, and 11th iteration. In 11th iteration the loop will stop because i will be equal to 11 causing the second condtion to pass.

Comment: None of the parts related to the flow of logic has anything to do with Julia, really, it would be the same in any language. The strange Julia-related part is the global declaration on `i`, which is needed when working in global scope. Just make sure to put your code in functions as much as possible.